# Implement standard Contact lookup as available on Task in a custom compone

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, tasks, modal, lightning-pill

There is a requirement where I need to implement same functionality as standard Contact lookup on Task [Screenshots Attached][image: Contact Lookup on Task][![enter image description here] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Y4q.png)][![enter image description here] [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO9II.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Y4q.png).
There is a custom component where I have multiple `</lightning:layout>` and creating a Task record after taking inputs from user. On this component I need to add a standard Contact lookup feature similar to what is available on Task.
The behaviour is like - on a custom modal pop-up, this standard Contact should be implemented[Standard functionality intact].

I want to know the approach. How do I achieve this..?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: NB: instead of developing your own UI for this component, consider whether you could achieve what you need using a screen flow. This already has a Lookup input component available for use in a screen.

Comment: Thanks @PhilW. Will try to put this in proper way. Also thanking for the screen flow suggestion. I can give it a try, but I think it won't work. Is there any solution we can think of that leverages LDS.?

Comment: There's no base component that provides lookup handling so if you can't use an embedded screen flow you will likely have to implement your own component, see if the [unofficialsf.com](https://unofficialsf.com/lookup/) lookup will help or consider starting from [JPipkin's component](https://github.com/JPipkin/LightningLookupComponent).

Comment: Actually, Task object is not supported on UI API. So this cannot be achieved using screen flow too.